# Optimising my greedy fuzzy search regex: limit it to words (separated by whitespace)

Tags: regex, autocomplete, fuzzy-search

I have an autocomplete which yields too many results, since I use a very greedy fuzzy search regex pattern: it simply looks for all the entered characters to appear anywhere (in the same order). This is done simply by adding a `.*?` to each and every entered character.

In the following example, typing `auto cont` results in the regex `a.*?u.*?t.*?o.*? .*?c.*?o.*?n.*?t.*?` and yields:

- `A`lternative texts of linked graphics m`u`s`t` describe link target `o`r purpose - 1.1.1 Non-text `Cont`ent - A
- `Auto`completes must be implemented in an accessible way - 4.1.2a Advanced `cont`rols (widgets)
- Bre`a`dcr`u`mbs or progress indica`to`rs must be re`co`g`n`izable non-visually - 1.3.1 Info and Rela`t`ionships - A

[image: Screenshot]

This is very useful when the autocomplete contains mainly very short options, but with longer ones, it tends to be confusing and it doesn't allow to narrow down the options in a quick and meaningful way.

So I want to change the behaviour: from now on, whitespace should limit the search, so the user can enter many terms (separated by whitespace) and each term is matched only against another term in the options.

This means, that in the above example, only the 2nd option should still be found, as both entered terms (`auto` and `cont`) exist as terms in the option (separated by whitespace):

- `Auto`completes must be implemented in an accessible way - 4.1.2a Advanced `cont`rols (widgets)

By the way, the search should still be fuzzy, so entering something like `atc trl` should still yield the result.

Answer (score 0):

> By the way, the search should still be fuzzy, so entering something
>   like atc trl should still yield the result.

I think what is greedy here is this logic above. This level of fuzziness will just yield too many results in most cases I can think of.

If you want to find results that only contain list of terms inside a single word like this:

- matching result: **auto**matically **cont**roll
- non matching result: bl**au** **to**pless dis**co** **nt**p protocol

than you can use this simple regex: `(auto)|(cont)`

This will also match results that have either of the 2, but you can sort them by number of found items per group to have results that are most relevant at the top.

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. Regarding the "too greedy" logic above: in German language, many words are built by concatenating single words, like "Landtier" (Land + Tier) or "Meerestier" (Meer + Tier). In this case it is useful to be able to search for "meti" and find "Meerestier", or for "tier" to get both "Landtier" and "Meerestier". So in my case, I'd love to keep my very greedy fuzzy search **within** single words.